# A coin is about to be tossed 50 times. Determine the probability the 4th heads occurs on the 10th toss.

Tags: probability

I got this: $(0.5)^4(0.5)^6\left(\frac{9!}{6!3!}\right)$

Is this right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Note that $\frac{9!}{6!3!}$ can be also written as $\binom{9}{3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are $\frac{9!}{6!3!}$ ways to get three heads in the first nine tosses, and each way has a probability of $0.5^9$.

Then there's a probability of $0.5$ of getting a head on the tenth toss.

Looks good to me!

The only thing that seems a little confusing to me is how you broke up $0.5^{10}$. If I were to write it out, I'd have done $(0.5)^9 {9 \choose 3} (0.5)$, or $(0.5)^{10} {9 \choose 3}$, but it amounts to the same thing.